# Consistent Lucene.NET runtime exception on certain queries

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, full-text-search, lucene.net

I'm putting together a proof of concept for Fulltext search in our application using Lucene.NET.  Some queries work fine, some seem to return results that don't match what the Luke tool is returning.  More problematically, this query:

```
(Description:tasty) (Gtin:00018389732061)
```

always yields this exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'
>   occurred in Lucene.Net.dll    at Lucene.Net.Search.TermScorer.Score()
>   in d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Search\TermScorer.cs:line 136
>   at
>   Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanScorer.BooleanScorerCollector.Collect(Int32
>   doc) in
>   d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Search\BooleanScorer.cs:line 88 
>   at Lucene.Net.Search.TermScorer.Score(Collector c, Int32 end, Int32
>   firstDocID) in
>   d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Search\TermScorer.cs:line 80
>   at Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanScorer.Score(Collector collector, Int32
>   max, Int32 firstDocID) in
>   d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Search\BooleanScorer.cs:line 323
>   at Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanScorer.Score(Collector collector) in
>   d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Search\BooleanScorer.cs:line 389
>   at Lucene.Net.Search.IndexSearcher.Search(Weight weight, Filter
>   filter, Collector collector) in
>   d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Search\IndexSearcher.cs:line 228
>   at Lucene.Net.Search.IndexSearcher.Search(Weight weight, Filter
>   filter, Int32 nDocs) in
>   d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Search\IndexSearcher.cs:line 188
>   at Lucene.Net.Search.Searcher.Search(Query query, Filter filter, Int32
>   n) in d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Search\Searcher.cs:line
>   108    at Lucene.Net.Search.Searcher.Search(Query query, Int32 n) in
>   d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Search\Searcher.cs:line 118
>   at...

If I use this query instead:

```
(Description:tasty) (Gtin:000)
```

I get results back.  What is causing the exception in the top query?  FWIW, here is the relevant code snippet:

```
protected virtual IList<Document> GetDocuments(BooleanQuery query, DirectoryInfo indexLocation, string defaultField)
        {
            var docs = new List<Document>();

            using (var dir = new MMapDirectory(indexLocation))
            {
                using (var searcher = new IndexSearcher(dir))
                {                        
                    var queryParser = new QueryParser(Constants.LuceneVersion, defaultField, new StandardAnalyzer(Constants.LuceneVersion));
                    TopDocs result = searcher.Search(query, Constants.MaxHits);

                    if (result == null) return docs;

                    foreach (var scoredoc in result.ScoreDocs.OrderByDescending(d => d.Score))
                    {
                        docs.Add(searcher.Doc(scoredoc.Doc));
                    }
                    return docs;
                }
            }
        }
```

Based on comments below, here is my current un-edited code that still doesn't work.

```
protected virtual IList<Document> GetDocuments(BooleanQuery query, DirectoryInfo indexLocation, string defaultField)
        {
            var docs = new List<Document>();

            using (var dir = new MMapDirectory(indexLocation))
            {
                using (var searcher = new IndexSearcher(dir))
                {
                    using (var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Constants.LuceneVersion))
                    {
                        var queryParser = new QueryParser(Constants.LuceneVersion, defaultField, analyzer);
                        var collector = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(Constants.MaxHits, true);
                        var parsed = queryParser.Parse(query.ToString());
                        searcher.Search(parsed, collector);

                        var docsresult = new List<string>();
                        var matches = collector.TopDocs().ScoreDocs;
                        foreach (var scoredoc in matches.OrderByDescending(d => d.Score))
                        {
                            docs.Add(searcher.Doc(scoredoc.Doc));
                        }
                        return docs;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Additionally, this query:  +(Description:tasty) +Gtin:000* returns no hits on my Lucene.NET impl, while Luke (correctly) returns 11 matching documents.

Comment: Is "Gtin" indexed as a string or numeric field?

Comment: Luke will often return "different" results as the analyzer is often different from how the fields were indexed

Comment: your example doesn't actually parse the query. It uses the BooleanQuery that's passed in.

Comment: Everything is handled as a string currently.  Can you help me understand the issue with the BooleanQuery?  I'm no expert with the framework.  A fluent query builder lib I'm using always produced a booleanquery.  Thanks.

Comment: Any multi-part query will end up as a BooleanQuery. Can I assume that the queries you've been referring to are the "ToString()" of the "query" arg? What is this "fluent query builder"? I've been using Lucene.net for many years. I've never had good experiences with 3rd party builders for anything other than the simple. I've always ended up either generating a query string and parsing it or, rarely, building the Query object graph directly. It's going to be hard to go further unless you can provide a fuller example somewhat like my Answer below.

Comment: Still going through this...actually I just got back on it.  I'm passing it in as the booleanQuery type, and the ToString() output appears correct.  The query builder is from github/lucene-fluent-query-builder.  So far I don't think that is the problem.  I'm comparing your impl with mine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not strictly an answer as it "works on my machine". Posting as an answer so that I can share the unit test code that "works". Hopefully the OP can show what is different with their version.

This version assumes that the "Gtin" field is a string field and is *not* analyzed (as it's seems to be a code).

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest4
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestLucene()
    {
        var writer = CreateIndex();
        Add(writer, "tasty", "00018389732061");
        writer.Flush(true, true, true);

        var searcher = new IndexSearcher(writer.GetReader());
        Test(searcher, "(Description:tasty) (Gtin:00018389732061)");
        Test(searcher, "Description:tasty Gtin:00018389732061");
        Test(searcher, "+Description:tasty +Gtin:00018389732061");
        Test(searcher, "+Description:tasty +Gtin:000*");

        writer.Dispose();
    }

    private void Test(IndexSearcher searcher, string query)
    {
        var result = Search(searcher, query);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
        Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual("00018389732061", result[0]);
    }

    private List<string> Search(IndexSearcher searcher, string expr)
    {
        using (var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30))
        {
            var queryParser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, "Description", analyzer);
            var collector = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(1000, true);
            var query = queryParser.Parse(expr);
            searcher.Search(query, collector);

            var result = new List<string>();
            var matches = collector.TopDocs().ScoreDocs;
            foreach (var item in matches)
            {
                var id = item.Doc;
                var doc = searcher.Doc(id);
                result.Add(doc.GetField("Gtin").StringValue);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    IndexWriter CreateIndex()
    {
        var directory = new RAMDirectory();

        var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);
        var writer = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, new IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength(1000));

        return writer;
    }
    void Add(IndexWriter writer, string desc, string id)
    {
        var document = new Document();
        document.Add(new Field("Description", desc, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
        document.Add(new Field("Gtin", id, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));

        writer.AddDocument(document);
    }
}
```

Comment: I apparently whiffed on the GTIN thing.  You are right.  That's a code field.  Did not realize the analyze setting should be set to false.  Gonna try that now...

Comment: OK, I tried a slight variation of yours.  I converted GTIN to not be analyzed.  Also I am converting the query to text. No joy.  Same error bubbling up out of the stack.  Note that I have a physical index, not in-mem so code is a little different...ack, code is too long, I will try to edit my original post

Comment: any field that contains a code/key/id type thing should be NOT_ANALYZED. The type of Directory used in the eample code will not make any difference to the behaviour. However, in lucene.net I don't think MMAPDirectory actually has any any benefits (there may even be bugs) could you try with a simple FSDirectory. Windows does a pretty good job of caching file contents. As the segment files are write once then readonly, you get pretty good perf characteristics anyway.

Comment: Apparently that was it!  It appears that FSDirectory is a base class so I used one of the derived classes - SimpleFSDirectory.  Magically it started working.

Comment: Ha! That'll teach me for making assumptions! BTW you shouldn't create SimpleFSDirectory directly. Use "FSDirectory.Open" (static method)

Comment: Thanks for all your help, sir.  I'm going to have to hand off this project to others on the team.  Do you have any recommendations for a best reference on this subject?  It seems like there are a lot of "best practices" that are not well documented.

Comment: Sorry, there's no convenient consolidated resource. Just lots of trial, error and pain. I ended up with a library that abstracted and hid all that stuff. Unfortunately, I don't think I can share it.
Don't Optimize; only ever have one Writer per folder, keep it as a singleton in your app; opening a Writer in an IIS hosted app is _not_ recommended. Open the Reader/Searcher from Writer.GetReader; Only use FSDirectory (or RamDirectory if appropriate, for small <1M docs. good for tests)... Good luck